# How to transfer this for loop from binomial tree method to price the option price into recursion in C++

Tags: c++, finance

```
for (int k = N-1; k >= 0; k--)
    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++)
      states[i] = states[i]*p + states[i+1]*(1-p);

return exp(-rate*T) * states[0];
```

"Here is the for loop from the binomial tree method to price the option price, and this step is backward iteration"

Comment: I wouldn't bother; recursion is useful for algorithms with a log(N) term in their big O; not here. Out of interest, why do you need to change any term other than `states[0]`? Are the mutated `states` elements used by the function caller?

Answer (score 0):

```
recurs(int k) {
    if (k > 0) recurs(k - 1);
    states[k] = states[k] * p + states[k + 1] * (1-p);
}
```